# ionic framework TypeError: Cannot read property 'udp' of undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, udp

cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp is installed but still get an error when i use this within ionic framework (testing on laptop - ionic serve)

i create 2 files index.html and app.js, see below:

the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- below line to allow access to outside website -->
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src 'self' data: *">
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
   <meta HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
   <meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <title>udpTest</title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen, projection">
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- Before cordova.js -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">>

    <ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">press key</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="connect()">
      lock
    </button>
    <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="connect()">
      unlock
    </button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the app.js file:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
//.factory('udpfact')
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
       $scope.connect = function() {
      var socketId;

      // Handle the "onReceive" event.
      var onReceive = function(info) {
        if (info.socketId !== socketId)
        return;
        console.log(info.data);
        };  

        // Create the Socket
chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function(socketInfo) {
  socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
  // Setup event handler and bind socket.
  chrome.sockets.udp.onReceive.addListener(onReceive);
  console.log("Just checking.");
  chrome.sockets.udp.bind(socketId,
    '', 5000, function(result) {
      if (result < 0) {
        console.log("Error binding socket.");
        return;
      }
      var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(20);
      var dv = new DataView(arrayBuffer,0);
      dv.setUint16(0,0);
      dv.setUint16(1,12);
      dv.setUint16(2,0);
      dv.setUint16(3,0);
      dv.setUint32(4,0);
      dv.setUint32(5,55555);
      dv.setUint32(6,0);
      console.log("here");
      chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, arrayBuffer,
        '255.255.255.255', 5000, function(sendInfo) {
          console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
      });
  });
});
  };
})
});
```

I have seen this is a problem for a lot, but at no platform I found a solution which was working. Any help or tips would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cordova plugins don't work in the browser. You'll need to test in an emulator or device.

Wrap your `chrome.sockets.udp.create....` in a block that checks if on cordova or not. Something like:

`if (chrome.sockets.udp) {.......}`

Comment: Better to do : `if (chrome && chrome.sockets && chrome.sockets.udp){...}`. Otherwise, you will have an exception.

Comment: After using the debug function (Xcode & safari + iPhone), it gives and error that chrome is not found.  Do I need to reference google somewhere? In other places e.g. 3djs you need to point to the js file within index.html. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I'm guessing chrome.sockets wouldn't exist in Safari

Comment: End goal is an Ionic App which is communicating with mine Raspberry Pi. As the local host name of the Raspberry is not always reachable I need the IP address of the Pi. So this is why I was thinking to let the App send an UDP message to the network (local) to get the IP address of the Pi. And by having this I can run my API’s on the Pi as I was doing in the past using my local name of the Pi. I also used the Ionic Framework in combination with some D3js for reporting and then I need to put this line <script src="lib/d3/d3.js"></script> to refer to the library. Do I not miss this now?

Comment: In the end I found the problem using npm is not installing correctly, you need sudo cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp